# Android: Multiple ListViews in one Activity - only one will update graphics

Tags: android, listview, adapter

have been sitting with this problem for a few days and really can't seem to find the answer myself.

I'm building an application for Android devices. The application will use a socket connection to a PC running a piece of software. The user have some buttons and stuff to change the state of the PC program - this part works well. Basicly by sending text to the PC using the socket.

I also want the Android application to handle incomming events from the PC. These events should alter the UI on the device in order to reflect the state of the PC program.

To understand my problem I will try to explain the structure of the app.
Basicly the app have four activities:

- A splash activity, which shows a splash screen and after a set time launches the next Activity
- A connector activity, which have an input where the user will type in the IP of the PC. When the device connects to the PC, the PC will send an xml file to the device basicly containing the state of the program. This xml file is parsed and when parsed without errors this activity launches the next Activity.
- The next activity is a TabActivity, creating 1 to 5 tabs, depending on the xml that was parsed. Each tab needs an activity which will handle the content for each tab. Here I have chosen to use one activity for all tabs.
- The last activity is the content activity. This is a ListActivity. When parsing the xml, items will be created and divided into 5 categories - one tab for each of these. When a tab is selected for the first time, the content will be generated, and a ListView object created for that tab. For each item in a category I inflate a layout (xml) and sets the correct graphics based on the state of the object. This works just fine. Switching between the tabs is fine aswell.

So - when switching tabs I check if the ListView for the tab is null, and if that is the case I will create the content, and if not then I will call the "setListAdapter(...)" with the correct "list.getAdapter()", where list will be the list related to the tab.

When receiving an event from the PC i have a Handler taking care of the event. This handler will parse the message, and find out what part of the UI to change, and what Object is related to this part of the UI. Then the state of the Object is changed to matter what - and if the obecjt's tab is currently open the View is changed aswell - if another View is opened a boolean will tell that an object in the tab has changed state.

I have tried to get the View from the ListView variable and change the child elements, but this do not work when the list is not the current list.

Then I tried to create a whole new ListView for the tab when the tab is getting pressed, if this boolean shows that something have been changed (just as it's created in the first place the first time) - this only works for one tab.

I've tried to test it with two of the tabs (2 and 3). The app starts on tab 1. If I then open tab 2 and then 3, sends commands to the PC from both tabs and all is fine. When the PC sends events to the app then only tab 3 will actually update. Working both when the tab is active and inactive (updates when getting active). While tab 2 does not update content on any changes.

If I only open tab 2 and not tab 3, then tab 2 will update in both cases just fine.

Anyone have any ideas to what can be done here?

I have tried all kinds of stuff with invalidate(), notifyDataSetChanged(), invalidateViews() etc, and nothing does the trick.

I really don't understand why, when creating a whole new ListView (from changed objects) that the old ListView will still be shown.

Did I shoot myself in the foot when choosing to use one activity for all tabs, or is this something else?

Hope someone can help me here.

And if some code is needed then please tell which part, as the app consist of ~15 classes and thousands of code lines, so I won't post it all :)

Cheers

Comment: put communication stuff to service, if new message come broadcast message, on ui part: if ui is active (onResume) register broadcast reciver and unregister it when becomes non active (onPause) ..... or put communication stuff to service, ui part bind service and do comunnication between ui and service as interface (read doc: AIDL)

Comment: I may have been bad at explaining the problem. My app is not running as a service, it's just an app that connects and communicates with a PC while the app is open and the software is running on the PC. When the app is closed, it will just disconnect and no more data should be received - this is working fine. As soon as the app connects to the service again a new xml file is received, parsed and UI is generated. This is a rather heavy process, so while the program is running the commands are just text that identify an object, the state of the object that changed and the new state.

Comment: thats why i think that you should use service ... service should keep underlaying objects fx.: array for ArrayAdpater  ... if you recive data from PC you only add it to this array and tell UI(with broadcast) "i got new array, refresh" ... if you change current tab (IIUYC, you rather changing adapter, not having ListView  for each tab) you could ask service ("hello service, geme lastest array for tab nr X", binding(better way) or by sending broadcast(from ui) to service which can response an array by sending another broadcast(service) ) ... heh i think should draw  it

Comment: I have never been working with services on Android, so I don't quite understand how that works to be honest. It might be a better way of acomplishing what I want to do. Actually what I did at first was making an adapter when the tab is first selected, and then save these adapters. Then when the tab was selected again at some point it just used the saved adapter. The commands from the PC was then changing the adapters as events came in. But the problem seemed that only one of the lists were actually reflecting the changes in the underlaying adapter - both could, but not at the same time.

Comment: Basicly the events from PC were sent to the Handler of the activity, which found the correct adapter, and the correct view in the adapter. Then found the views in this view that needed to be updated and updated the views according to the event. The next time the tab with that adapter was pressed it set the modified adapter as the listadapter, but the changes in the adapter was not shown in the UI. (tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() at different places, but didn't do anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with one activity for each tab content instead of the first approach where I had one Activity for them all and just switching between adapters for the listview when a tab was pressed.

Splitting it into an activity for each tab made it possible for all content to be changed no matter if the activity was showing or not.